# Can't login with user created on custom form - Django

Tags: django, forms, django-registration, django-login, django-custom-user

I have written a custom form for the creation of a user.
The login works for the users created on the terminal with "python manage.py createsuperuser", but it doesn't work for the users created on the website. I have checked, and the creation form works; I mean, the user is created.

This is the **form**

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
"""
A form that creates a user, with no privileges, from the given email and password.
"""

def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
    super(CustomUserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class Meta:
    model = CustomUser
    fields = ("email",)
```

The **model**

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username     = models.CharField(max_length=254, unique=True, null=True)
    first_name   = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    second_name  = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    email        = models.EmailField(blank=True, unique=True)
    address1     = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    address2     = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    area_code    = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    date_joined  = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=datetime.now())
    is_active    = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin     = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff     = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'address1', 'address2', 'area_code', 'country_code']

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%s" % urlquote(self.email)

    def get_full_name(self):
        """
        Returns the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
        """
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        """
        Returns the first name for the user.
        """ 
        return self.first_name

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None):
        """
        Sends an email to this user.
        """
        send_email(subject, message, from_email, [self.email])
```

The **register view**

```
def register(request):

    registered = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = CustomUserCreationForm(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()

            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            registered = True

        else:
            print user_form.errors
    else:
        user_form = CustomUserCreationForm()

    return render(request, 'register.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'registered': registered})
```

The **login view**

```
def login(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        login_form = CustomUserLoginForm(data=request.POST)

        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                auth.login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Your account is disabled.")
        else:
            print "Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(username, password)
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied. Get back to the <a href=\"/\">homepage</a>.")

    else:
        login_form = CustomUserLoginForm()

    return render(request, 'login.html', {'login_form': login_form})
```

What am I missing here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First fix the class:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser, PermissionsMixin):
```

AbstractUser is a real User Model, the BaseUser is just the meta class.

To create a new user you should use this line, in the form or in the register view:

```
User.objects.create_user(username=username,email=email,password=password)
```

Note that `set_password` is used to change the password, and it logs out this user after the password changes.

Comment: If I try to do that, the error is: "Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'custom_user.CustomUser'", and I think that is because I have defined an AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'custom_user.CustomUser'.


How do I solve that?

Answer (score 1):

For almost three days I was trying to overcome same issue. I even wrote AUTHENTICATION_BACKEND. Only after that, a message was displayed on the form that the user is not active. When in save method I assigned True to user.is_active

```
def save(self):
    user = super().save(commit=False)
    user.is_active = True
    user.save()
```

This worked for me. I hope it will work for you as well. (Note: I was not aware of rules and posted same message for similar questions to help others as well, when get notice not to do it. If anyone will see my answer for other questions please ignore it. The above answer is edited one and mostly related to this exact issue)